# como hago que un metodo se ejecute pasado X tiempo despues de apretar un boton?

Tags: java

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que pasados X segundos despues de ejecutado un boton me mande a un metodo que haga lo que tenga que hacer.

un poco del contexto: tengo un boton que al darle se muestra un jLabel1 con un .gif
entonces quiero que a la mitad delgif del jLabel1 se ejecute un metodo que me muestre un jLabel2.

```
   private void golpearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   int x = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Pasaron x segundos pa que se baje la barra de vida");

    //Esperar el tiempo y mandar al metodo
   ataca(x);

}
```

basicamente quiero que halla un Delay para que el gif este donde quiero que este y luego si ejecutar ese metodo `ataca(x)`para asi tener una "sincronizacion"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a dormir el  hilo que este pasando en ese momento por esa clase 
 `Thread.sleep(10000)`, son milisegundos, aunque creo que no podrás ejecutar otras sentencias  a la vez que haces el sleep, para ello deberías de crear tu mismo el hilo ya sea con Runneable o extendiendo de Thread y gestionarlos mediante un run.

Si tienes cualquier otra duda comenta.